# List field contents not displaying with .val function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running this script in a custom script box of some workflow software. 
I want the user to have specific fields hide or show based on the list value.  This script is on pages after the user picked the list field value.  So this loads on a page where the list field is populated. The script works - it shows and hides the correct fields, BUT it makes the value selected not visible. The field is there, but the value is blank.

I've also tried removing the `document.ready` function at the beginning.  I've tried removing val(function() and putting it all into the `if` statement.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ctl00_mainContent_qtWfInstance_ctl00_ctl01_lstValues").val(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "One") {
      $("#CustomFieldWrapper_1277_0_0").show();
      $("#CustomFieldWrapper_1303_0_0").hide();
    }
    if ($(this).val() == "Two") {
      $("#CustomFieldWrapper_1303_0_0").show();
      $("#CustomFieldWrapper_1277_0_0").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

I'm wondering why the list field's selected value doesn't display?  The drop down is there, and the list field can be updated (it is editable on the next step).  It is showing and hiding correctly based on the value that was selected in the last step.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.val(index, value)` default parameters.

**EDIT:** And as @BrandonHill suggested, return the input value at the end of your function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ctl00_mainContent_qtWfInstance_ctl00_ctl01_lstValues").val(function(index, value) {
        if (value == "One") {
            $("#CustomFieldWrapper_1277_0_0").show();
            $("#CustomFieldWrapper_1303_0_0").hide();
        }
        if (value == "Two") {
            $("#CustomFieldWrapper_1303_0_0").show();
            $("#CustomFieldWrapper_1277_0_0").hide();
        }
      return value; // Add this line
    });
});
```

The reason is that, using `.val()` defines its selector the value returned inside, and if you don't have any return it will return `undefined` which won't be equal to `One` nor `Two` anytime.

> For this to work, `#ctl00_mainContent_qtWfInstance_ctl00_ctl01_lstValues` **must** be an input.

For more information you can read [jQuery official documentation](https://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function).

Comment: Shouldn't they just change `.val()` to `.change()`...?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts actually both works. The main thing to notice here is that user must ensure that his selector is an input.

Comment: Regardless of using arguments or not, the return value is what the input value gets set to.

Comment: @BrandonHill then using `.change()` is the way.

Comment: @k3llydev not if it's expected to run on `ready` as the code suggests.

Comment: @BrandonHill but won't using `.val()` and not having a return sentence, should convert this unexisting return to undefined?

Comment: That's exactly the problem. An absence of a return statement is the same as `return undefined`, which is what the input is getting set to. It should be `return arguments[1]` (or `return value` for your sample).

Comment: @BrandonHill I got you now. I edited my answer specifying this.

Comment: The fix is not to use `change` (that's an event handler - the op is executing on `ready`), and your statement under the code block is incorrect. The op says the conditions _are_ functioning as expected, it's just that the input value is being cleared, which is solved by simply returning `value`. Kinda like my answer already suggested :)

Comment: @BrandonHill done. I think I just edited too fast that I didn't even did the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

This is jQuery, not javascript. The `.val(function)` method will set the input value to the returned value of the function, which in this case is null/undefined. If you accept the second argument in your function you can just return that.

Comment: Was wondering how long that would take :) I just meant it should have the tag `jQuery`. Nit picker :)

Comment: Well, toss a softball like that... ;-P

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much!!!!  It now shows the value in the box and if I change the value and save the workflow, it re-loads the page with the new value and showing the correct fields!

All I did was add the 
    return value;
line.  I did not add the (index, value)  I left that as ().